# SQL Server trim function

Tags: sql-server

I have a problem in SQL Server. I want to remove space using Ltrim and Rtrim.

My query is like this

```
select len('test        ')
```

Return 6

```
select len(rtrim(ltrim('test        ')))
```

Return 6

Why Its not Removing space?

I have checked the ascii values for this space is 32.

Any help?

Thank you

Comment: Can you double check they are actually spaces on the end? As @MarekGrzenkowicz has suggested, if they are tabs that would explain it...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because there are no spaces in this string - after `test` there are **two horizontal tab  characters** (`\t`).

[image: Tabs, not spaces]

Comment: Excellent answer. Certainly explains the Len() count of 6 but what about the ascii code? +1

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't quite make sense to me as:

```
SELECT LEN('test  ')
```

should return 4, not 6 - LEN() will **NOT** count trailing spaces.

Whereas if you did:

```
SELECT DATALENGTH('test    ')
```

this would return 6 as DATALENGTH **does** count trailing spaces.

Comment: It returns 6 because there are no spaces in the string - [these are tabs](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9618274/95).

Comment: @MarekGrzenkowicz - that would explain it. Though OP said he'd checked and they were ascii 32 (space)

Comment: Let's wait and see if OP replies to your comment. For me the hint was that the 1st query returned 6 and the string looked longer than that.

Answer (score 1):

Len [Returns the number of characters of the specified string expression, excluding trailing blanks.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190329.aspx)

Therefore, len is not counting the extra trailing blanks in your string. If you put the blanks before the string, then those will be counted.

- select len('test ') (len = 4)
- select len(' test') (len = 5)

Answer (score 0):

Actually the space is getting trimmed in both cases and that's by standard in SQL server. (len does the trimming)

Comment: Its not getting trimmed, its not being counted in the first case.